# How to Set ListView Divider Color With hex Color?

Tags: android, listview, colors, divider

I am using this code to set ListView divider with hex color and it doesnot work!!

```
ListView list = (ListView) act.findViewById(R.id.menu_listview);

SlideMenuItem[] items = menuItemList
        .toArray(new SlideMenuItem[menuItemList.size()]);

SlideMenuAdapter adap = new SlideMenuAdapter(act, items, font);

// side menu divider color
 list.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000")));
list.setAdapter(adap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It doesn't work" is no problem description, but I guess the divider is not appearing... try :

```
list.setDividerHeight( xyz );
```

...and make sure everything else isn't black as well.